# export excel sheet with where condition of sql in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, export, where-clause, maatwebsite-excel

```
public function cal1(request $request){
       $request->validate([
         'month' => 'required'
       ]);
       $month1 = $request->get('month');
      // dd($month1);
      $date = DB::table('users')->where('date', '==', $month1);
       return Excel::download(new UsersExport($date), 'users.xlsx');
    
}
```

here is my controller, it exports the excel sheet with all the data in DB table. I want to export excel sheet having data month wise. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `where('date', $month1)` or  `where('date',  '=' , $month1)`. No need to use double equal here

Comment: [Basic Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses) You use `=` in sql, not `==`

Comment: i have tried '=' but the result is same

Comment: what is the value of `$month1` and is `date` a date type column??

Comment: both values are same as 2021-03-25, yes date is a date type column. @zahidhasanemon

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was stucked in controller, I put where condition in controller rather I had to put it on export file. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-
$date = DB::table('users')->where('date', '=', $month1)->get();

Comment: I have tried '=' but I am getting the same result.

Comment: Try this now,
$date = DB::table('users')->whereDate('date', $month1)->get();

Comment: I have tried all these methods. @VarinderKaur

Answer (score 0):

To get specified month, use ***whereMonth()***, to make it also filtered by month and year, use ***whereDate()***. Its not recommended to use ***whereYear()*** and ***whereMonth()*** in one query

```
DB::table('table')->whereMonth('date', $month1)->get();
DB::table('table')->whereDate('date', 'like', $month1 . '%')->get();
```

[Laravel Docs Query](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)